# Cursor type in Emacs

Tags: emacs, customization, preferences, text-cursor

What do I put in my .emacs file to change the cursor type for all frames to `box`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Before Emacs 23.2, you should do :

```
(setq default-cursor-type 'box)
```

Be careful, `default-cursor-type` is a variable that is obsolete since Emacs 23.2.
You should use `cursor-type` variable instead :

```
(set-default 'cursor-type 'box)
```

Comment: Also note that when using cygwin, mintty overrides the cursor (right-click on mintty header to get to options and set the one you like).

Answer (score 3):

Got it, it's:

`(setq default-cursor-type 'box)`